# Oracle Get files of temp tablespace

Tags: oracle

I found two ways of getting the  files of temp tablespace which is better way.

1. `SELECT FILE_NAME  FROM DBA_TEMP_FILES WHERE TABLESPACE_NAME = 'APSRM2_TEMP'`
2. `SELECT name FROM V$TEMPFILE WHERE ts#=(SELECT ts# FROM V$TABLESPACE WHERE name = 'APSRM2_TEMP' );`

Answer (score 0):

V$TABLESPACE = "Name and number of all tablespaces from the control file."

DBA_TEMP_FILES="Shows files (tempfiles) belonging to temporary tablespaces."

So first one is better like this

"SELECT  FILE_NAME FROM TABLESPACE_NAME FROM DBA_DATA_FILES;"
Output = "/U02/ORACLE/IDDB3/DBF/RBS01.DBF                   RBS"